# Merge two GeoJSON files into one creating connection between parcel info and object info

Tags: qgis, geojson, merge

I have two GeoJSON files, one with parcel info (multiplygons) and one with object on the parcel info (multipolygons). The files have exactly the same attributes. What would be the best way to join them together and load into database (Elastic for example). So far when I load them into elastic I get two indexes and I can query the parcels, and search for object multipolygons in another index, but it is not performant. Is there a way to join these into single GeoJSON object (parcel and objects polygon coordinates)? The attributes are the same so they can be copied over.

Comment: Which software or programming language are you using?

Comment: QGIS to generate shape file. Export to geojson data from qgis, resulting in two geojson files. One for parcels and one for objects on parcels. The isussue is that i dont have any connection for parcel -> object in geojson. For every match i need to query two times. Load it to elastic search (create two indexes), and query it from elastic and display via maplibre.